# Why is the text on the right being cut out when there's still so much space remaining within the button?

Tags: android-layout

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/space"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:textSize="70sp" />
```

I'm using the above code for the button but the right side of my text on the button is being cutoff despite there being so much space on the button. Am I missing out something?

I've learnt Java till grade 12 but learnt some basic XML for App Dev quite recently so I'm not aware of how to fix the issue. I tried looking for a solution but wasn't successful. If there is any additional info that needs to be mentioned, if I need to dig some more or if these kind of questions aren't entertained here, please let me know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[This shows a screenshot of how the app. I decided to make (calculator) looks on my phone(moto G5).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7YPg.png)

Comment: HERE DESCRIBED HERE TRY THIS METHOD
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/270171/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83

Comment: @EvgenySermyagin Hi, i looked into the link but there is no answer to that question. moreover i tried to use the suggestion given in one of the comment and it didn't help in way.